# Change axios Response Schema

Tags: vue.js, xmlhttprequest, axios

As [axios GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) page states, default response of axios request is:

```
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
  request: {}
}
```

**Problem:**

My API response schema is:

```
{
  success: true,
  message: '',
  data: {}
}
```

So every time I make a request, I have to handle the response like:

```
(...).then((res) => res.data.data);
```

How can I change the response schema of axios to avoid doing `.data.data` every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a response interceptor to change the value of the promise:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response.data.data
})
```

You'd just do this once and then it would apply to all requests made via the default `axios` instance. A similar approach can be taken if you're creating your own `axios` instances using `axios.create`.

You may also need to consider how to handle error cases but the approach is much the same.

Documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

**Update:**

If you need access to `success`, `message` and `data` you would just need this instead:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response.data
})
```

Destructuring would potentially be useful when you write the `then` handler:

```js
(...).then(({ data, success, message }) => {

});
```

Comment: I'm aware of the response interceptors but I need the other props from actual response too, can't just simply discard half response of API. That's why title says `change **axios** response schema` not the API's response.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I don't entirely follow what you're asking but I still believe response interceptors are the answer. Perhaps you just need `return response.data`? Could you update the question to include an example of what you want?

Comment: I don't want the axios to wrap the actual API response in to a custom object.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Could you clarify how that differs from using `return response.data` within the interceptor? Doing it that way you would get an object with the properties `success`, `message` and `data`, which seems to be what you're asking for. If that isn't what you're asking for it would be massively helpful if you could update the question to provide a clear and complete description of what you want. Currently it just asks how to avoid `.data.data` but doesn't specifically say what you'd like instead.

Comment: apologize, my bad! I was confusing `interceptors` with `transformResponse` hook because I tried that n it didn't work. just read ur comment carefully, let me try with interceptors...

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I've updated my answer to show the `return response.data` case more clearly.

Comment: `interceptors` did the trick. I was already using them for adding auth token but didn't click my mind for this. I ended up returning custom object bcz I'd need http status too. anyways, thanks a lot, much appreciated!